# Passing string to dataframe iloc

Tags: python, pandas, python-3.5

I have a `ProductDf` which have many versions of the same product. I want to filter the last iteration of the product. So I did this as below:

```
productIndexDf= ProductDf.groupby('productId').apply(lambda 
x:x['startDtTime'].reset_index()).reset_index()        

productToPick = productIndexDf.groupby('productId')['index'].max()
```

get the value of productToPick into a string

```
productIndex = productToPick.to_string(header=False, 
index=False).replace('\n',' ')
productIndex  = productIndex.split()

productIndex = list(map(int, productIndex))
productIndex.sort()

productIndexStr = ','.join(str(e) for e in productIndex)
```

Once I get that in a Series, I call loc function manually and it works:

```
filteredProductDf = ProductDf.iloc[[7,8],:]
```

If I pass it the string, I get an error:

```
filteredProductDf = ProductDf.iloc[productIndexStr,:]
```

`ValueError: Location based indexing can only have [integer, integer slice (START point is INCLUDED, END point is EXCLUDED), listlike of integers, boolean array] types`

I also tried this:

```
filteredProductDf = ProductDf[productIndexStr]
```

But then I get this issue:

```
KeyError: '7,8'
```

Comment: Can you share some data with us? `print(ProductDf.head(5).to_dict())`

Comment: print(ProductDf.head(5).to_dict())
{'startDtTime': {0: '01/05/2018', 1: '02/05/2018', 2: '03/05/2018', 3: '01/05/2018', 4: '02/05/2018'}, 'totalSold': {0: 100, 1: 150, 2: 300, 3: 220, 4: 250}, 'productId': {0: 'A001', 1: 'A001', 2: 'A001', 3: 'A002', 4: 'A002'}, 'avgPrice': {0: 42.5, 1: 55.5, 2: 48.5, 3: 42.5, 4: 53.5}}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I think you are confusing it.

Given a dataframe that look like this:

```
   avgPrice productId startDtTime  totalSold
0      42.5      A001  01/05/2018        100
1      55.5      A001  02/05/2018        150
2      48.5      A001  03/05/2018        300
3      42.5      A002  01/05/2018        220
4      53.5      A002  02/05/2018        250
```

I assume that you are interested in row 2 and 4 (the last value of respective productId). In pandas the easiest way would be to use `drop_duplicates()` with the param `keep='last'`. Consider this example:

```
import pandas as pd

d = {'startDtTime': {0: '01/05/2018', 1: '02/05/2018', 
                     2: '03/05/2018', 3: '01/05/2018', 4: '02/05/2018'}, 
 'totalSold': {0: 100, 1: 150, 2: 300, 3: 220, 4: 250}, 
 'productId': {0: 'A001', 1: 'A001', 2: 'A001', 3: 'A002', 4: 'A002'}, 
 'avgPrice': {0: 42.5, 1: 55.5, 2: 48.5, 3: 42.5, 4: 53.5}
    } 

# Recreate dataframe
ProductDf = pd.DataFrame(d)

# Convert column with dates to datetime objects
ProductDf['startDtTime'] = pd.to_datetime(ProductDf['startDtTime'])

# Sort values by productId and startDtTime to ensure correct order
ProductDf.sort_values(by=['productId','startDtTime'], inplace=True)

# Drop the duplicates
ProductDf.drop_duplicates(['productId'], keep='last', inplace=True)

print(ProductDf)
```

And you get:

```
   avgPrice productId startDtTime  totalSold
2      48.5      A001  2018-03-05        300
4      53.5      A002  2018-02-05        250
```

Comment: Yes - this works very well. I also discovered this may work too: filteredProductDf = ProductDf.iloc[productIndex,:]  But this is all long winded, and your solution is much more simple and elegant! Thanks

Answer (score 4):

Pandas Dataframe **iloc** method works only with integer type indexed value. If you want to use string value as index for accessing data from pandas dataframe then you have to use Pandas Dataframe **loc** method.

Know more about these method from these link.

[Use of Pandas Dataframe *iloc* method](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.iloc.html)

[Use of Pandas Dataframe *loc* method](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html)

Comment: It's best to include the relevant detail from any links you include in your answer as this saves other users' time and also guards against the links dying.